# How to specify height in css class in flexbox layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having this simple example of a flexbox with the height specified in the box class. However, the height of the divs remains at 0. Ofcourse when I specify the height inline its shows me what I'm trying to achieve. What am I missing?

Thanks for the help. Apparently there was a problem with embedding the style. Not it works like a charm. Thanks. I updated the code.

```css
.container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .box {
        height: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }

    header {
      width: 100%;
      order: 1;
      background-color: lime;
    }

    .red {
      width: 50%;
      order: 2;
      background-color: red;
    }

    .orange {
      width: 50%;
      order: 3;
      background-color: orange;
    }

    footer {
      width: 100%;
      order: 4;
      background-color: magenta;
    }

    .light_blue {
      width: 20%;
      order: 5;
      background-color: lightblue;
    }

    .dark_blue {
      width: 60%;
      order: 6;
      background-color: blue;
    }

    .green {
      width: 20%;
      order: 7;
      background-color: green;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <header class="box lime"></header>
    <div class="box red"></div>
    <div class="box orange"></div>
    <footer class="box"></footer>
    <div class="box light_blue"></div>
    <div class="box dark_blue"></div>
    <div class="box green"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Your example shows me boxes with 100px height, which browser are you using?

Comment: What could be missing? > 1/ Autoprefixer if you support anything else than current Edge/Fx/Chr/Saf (like IE10 and 11, etc) 2/ Real content in those flex items (lorem ipsum or alike) because no content and no height => null height